# Change JavaScript property based upon other property (language)

Tags: javascript, json

I want to change the object `department_descr` with JavaScript based on the language:

```
var data = {
  "language": "EN",    
  "contacts": [
    {
      "department_descr": {
        "en": "Management",
        "fr": "Gestion"
      }
    }
  ]
};
```

output:

```
{  
  "language": "EN",  
  "contacts": [
    {
      "department_descr": "Management"
    }       
  ]
}
```

Comment: These are JavaScript objects. JSON is a serialisation format where data is converted into *text*.

Comment: what you have tried?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, your example object is malformed, which will cause a syntax error. Change it to this:

```
var data = {
  "language": "EN",    
  "contacts": [
      {
        "department_descr": {
          "en": "Management",
          "fr": "Gestion"
        }
      }
  ]
}
```

Second, changing the object is not recommended in this case. You should create a new object using the model you need:

```
var desc = data.contacts[0].department_descr[data.language.toLowerCase()];
var newData = Object.assign({}, data, { contacts: [ { department_descr: desc } ] })
```

Comment: Great :-) Mark it as answer so others will find it

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that will take, as an argument, an object like that and set the description based upon the language property.

Technically it returns a *new* object rather than mutating the existing object, but that's what you want in the vast majority of cases.

```
function setDescription(srcObject){
    let language = srcObject.language.toLowerCase();
    let outputObj = Object.assign({}, srcObject);
    outputObj.contacts = srcObject.contacts.map((contact) =>{
        let newDescription = contact.department_descr[language];
        contact.department_descr = newDescription;
        return contact;
    });
    return outputObj;
}
```

This will work for an arbitrary length of the contacts array. It has certain assumptions.

1. The language in the contacts array is the lower case country code ('en').
2. The matching language country code required for the contacts is found in the 'language' property of the same object.
3. The 'contacts' property exists and is an array.

Answer (score 0):

**Demo :**

```js
var data = {
  "language": "EN",    
  "contacts": [
    {
      "department_descr": {
        "en": "Management",
        "fr": "Gestion"
      }
    }
  ]
};

for (var i of data.contacts) {
 if(Object.keys(i.department_descr).includes(data.language.toLowerCase()) === true) {
   i.department_descr = i.department_descr[data.language.toLowerCase()];
 }
}

console.log(data);
```